# no method error on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm beginner of rails. what I'm trying to do is making a form which has only title and content and building a database that can save them.

This is my migrate file

```
class CreateMelons < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :melons do |t|

      t.string :title
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And this is my controller

```
 def write
        @title =params[:title]
        @content = params[:content]

        @new_post = Melon.new
        @new_post.title =params[:title]
        @new_post.content =params[:content]
        @new_post.save

        redirect_to "/list"


    end
```

And the error messages are here.

```
undefined method `title=' for #<Melon id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I don't know what the reason is.
There's title column!
And I've executed rake db:migrate command.
Please help me!

Comment: Can you show the text from your melon.rb model?

Comment: You don't have title for this model `#<Melon id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

Comment: Did you update the same migration or have you ever migrated it

Comment: try to `rake db:rollback` and `rake db:migrate`

Comment: @moveson All I have is just class Melon < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Comment: @Deepak I did... but same error raise.

Comment: Can you try `Melon.new` in rails console what does it returns

Comment: @Deepak Melon.new returns command not found... that's strange.

Comment: restart console once

Comment: I did. it doesn't work. Is that right to type Melon.new on my bash? And I'm using the c9 console.

Comment: Oh I get it. Melon.new command returns this message. #<Melon id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Comment: could you paste the melon table from the `schema.rb` file ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady oh my god... schema file was the problem.. thanks Mohammad!

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I have question again.. How can I change the schema.rb file? I wrote title and content in my schema.rb file, but after I execute rake db:migrate, they are gone.

Comment: I think you changed the migration file after running the migration it self, rails won't run the same migration file again because it's marked as already done, you have 2 solutions for this, either rollback and re-run the migration file again ( like someone suggested above ) or add the new column in a separate migration file.

Comment: oh I got it. I did rake db:drop and rake db:migrate. It worked! thank you all!

Comment: @JeongmyeongLee would you like to add the steps and conclusions as an answer below?

Comment: @phss I did. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I will answer my own question.

'No method error' of ruby on rails appears when there's no such method in  schema.rb file or attr accessor in your model.

Therefore, you should add your method such as tilte, content in your migration file and MIGRATE your database to refresh schcema.rb file.

Or you can simply add the method as attr accessor if you don't want additional column for your database.

Comment: You really don't have to drop your database to migrate it. Otherwise people wouldn't be able to run migrations in production.

Comment: @MichaelKohl I eddited. Thanks!